# How to select columns with names as dates using dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis

I have dataframe where some headers have names a character and dates. I want to select all the columns which dont have dates as header and all the columns which have the dates less than the current date or system date(sys.date()). How can I do thins using select statement in dplyr.

Below is the dataframe

```
> dput(job_times[1:5,])
structure(list(Skill = c("KAC", "KAC", "KAC", "KAC", "KAC"), 
    Patch = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), `Work Code` = c("W01", 
    "W01", "W01", "W01", "W01"), Product = c("KAC Repair", "KAC Repair", 
    "KAC Repair", "KAC Repair", "KAC Repair"), `Visit Time` = c(45.68, 
    42.55, 46.45, 51.86, 43.49), Travel = c(32.5, 21.66, 26.33, 
    28.63, 27.03), Success = c(0.69, 0.66, 0.67, 0.65, 0.67), 
    `Completion Time` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `28-12-2020` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `04-01-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `11-01-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `18-01-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `25-01-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `01-02-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `08-02-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `15-02-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `22-02-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `01-03-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `08-03-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `15-03-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `22-03-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `29-03-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `05-04-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `12-04-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `19-04-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `26-04-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `03-05-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `10-05-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `17-05-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `24-05-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `31-05-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `07-06-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `14-06-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `21-06-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `28-06-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `05-07-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `12-07-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `19-07-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `26-07-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `02-08-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `09-08-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `16-08-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `23-08-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `30-08-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `06-09-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `13-09-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `20-09-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `27-09-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `04-10-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `11-10-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `18-10-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `25-10-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `01-11-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `08-11-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `15-11-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `22-11-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `29-11-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `06-12-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `13-12-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `20-12-2021` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `27-12-2021` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `03-01-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `10-01-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `17-01-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `24-01-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `31-01-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `07-02-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `14-02-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `21-02-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `28-02-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `07-03-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `14-03-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `21-03-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `28-03-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `04-04-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `11-04-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `18-04-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `25-04-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `02-05-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `09-05-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `16-05-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `23-05-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `30-05-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `06-06-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `13-06-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `20-06-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `27-06-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `04-07-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `11-07-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `18-07-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `25-07-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `01-08-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `08-08-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `15-08-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `22-08-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `29-08-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `05-09-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `12-09-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `19-09-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `26-09-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `03-10-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `10-10-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `17-10-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `24-10-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `31-10-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `07-11-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `14-11-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `21-11-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `28-11-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `05-12-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 
    2.05, 1.74), `12-12-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), 
    `19-12-2022` = c(1.9, 1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74), `26-12-2022` = c(1.9, 
    1.61, 1.8, 2.05, 1.74)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want the Skill, Patch, Work Code, Product, Visit Time, Travel, Success, Completion Time columns along with all the columns which have their dates less than or equal to sys.Date(). Using dplyr and select statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it -

```
cols <- grep('\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}', names(job_times), value = TRUE)
result <- job_times[, c(setdiff(names(job_times), cols), 
              cols[Sys.Date() > as.Date(cols, '%d-%m-%Y')])]
```

You can integrate this in `dplyr` pipe as -

```
library(dplyr)

job_times %>%
  select({
    cols <- grep('\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}', names(.), value = TRUE)
    c(setdiff(names(.), cols),
      cols[Sys.Date() > as.Date(cols, '%d-%m-%Y')])
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a helper function and then you can use select like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

is_before_today <- function(x) {
  (dmy(x, quiet = TRUE) < Sys.Date()) %>% coalesce(FALSE)
}

df %>% 
  select(
    matches("^\\D"), all_of(colnames(.) %>% keep(is_before_today))
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 38
#>   Skill Patch `Work Code` Product   `Visit Time` Travel Success `Completion Tim~
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>       <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 KAC   A1    W01         KAC Repa~         45.7   32.5    0.69             1.9 
#> 2 KAC   A2    W01         KAC Repa~         42.6   21.7    0.66             1.61
#> 3 KAC   A3    W01         KAC Repa~         46.4   26.3    0.67             1.8 
#> 4 KAC   A4    W01         KAC Repa~         51.9   28.6    0.65             2.05
#> 5 KAC   A5    W01         KAC Repa~         43.5   27.0    0.67             1.74
#> # ... with 30 more variables: 28-12-2020 <dbl>, 04-01-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   11-01-2021 <dbl>, 18-01-2021 <dbl>, 25-01-2021 <dbl>, 01-02-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   08-02-2021 <dbl>, 15-02-2021 <dbl>, 22-02-2021 <dbl>, 01-03-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   08-03-2021 <dbl>, 15-03-2021 <dbl>, 22-03-2021 <dbl>, 29-03-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   05-04-2021 <dbl>, 12-04-2021 <dbl>, 19-04-2021 <dbl>, 26-04-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   03-05-2021 <dbl>, 10-05-2021 <dbl>, 17-05-2021 <dbl>, 24-05-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   31-05-2021 <dbl>, 07-06-2021 <dbl>, 14-06-2021 <dbl>, 21-06-2021 <dbl>,
#> #   28-06-2021 <dbl>, 05-07-2021 <dbl>, 12-07-2021 <dbl>, 19-07-2021 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful comment Jason. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Well your answer still returns 113 columns

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - just fixed the error.

Answer (score -1):

Ronak Shah's answer is extremely great. Here is how I'll do.

```
    ## Get the List of All Column Names
    ColumnNames <- names(TestDF)

    ## Retain Only those don't have Dates
    CharacterColumnNames <- ColumnNames[grepl( "[[:alpha:]]" , names( TestDF ) )] 

    ## Get the List of all Date Column Names
    DateColumns <- setdiff(names(TestDF),CharacterColumnNames)

    ## Filter Required Date Column Names
    RequiredDateColumns <- DateColumns[ Sys.Date() > as.Date(DateColumns, '%d-%m-%Y')]

    ## Get the Modified DF
    ModifiedDF <- TestDF[, c(CharacterColumnNames, RequiredDateColumns)]
```